# ggplot match color code column to another column in R dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I have this simple dataframe in the form:

```
x    y    tissue    color_code
1    2    nerve     #EEEE00
2    3    brain     #33CCCC
```

There are several thousands rows for each tissue.  Each tissue will have the same color_code (e.g. all rows with nerve have a color code of #EEEE00,etc.)

I would like to make a simple line plot of y vs x and color by tissue using the corresponding color code.

The code I have so far looks like this

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y,color=tissue))+
   geom_point()+
   scale_color_manual(values=df$color_code)
```

However, the colors end up all being the same color.

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. There is a typo in `=color=tissue`, remove the first equal sign and change `geom_line` to `geom_point`, since there is only one data point of each tissue, and everything works as expected, one point is red and the other is black.

Comment: I just fixed the errors.  EEEE00 in hex corresponds to yellow, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having your colors come from another column in the data frame runs the risk of things not coming through in the right order, as happened when I ran your code as it is. The tissue gets mapped to color in a certain order, either based on factor levels if it's already a factor, or in alphabetical order if it isn't. But `df$color_code` will just be a vector of colors, and will assign colors in the order they appear. So with your code as it is, I'm getting the light yellow color placed with "brain" instead of "nerve" because of the mismatch between this ordering.

This also is likely to not scale well—say you've got two observations of "brain," which would mean you're putting the "brain" color (teal) into the palette twice.

What I'd do instead is use the data to create a named vector of colors, where each occurs once. The names mean your colors will be matched to the correct categories regardless of order.

I've added a couple more observations to show.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- tribble(
  ~x,  ~y,  ~tissue,  ~color_code,
   1,   2,   "nerve",  "#EEEE00",
   2,   3,   "brain",  "#33CCCC",
   3,   2.5, "other",  "#DD55AA",
   4,   1,   "nerve",  "#EEEE00"
)

colors <- distinct(df, tissue, color_code)
pal <- colors$color_code
names(pal) <- colors$tissue
pal
#>     nerve     brain     other 
#> "#EEEE00" "#33CCCC" "#DD55AA"

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, color = tissue)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values = pal)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-03-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>